# Not returning any results even though I scraped a different section of the domain without an issue

Tags: scrapy

I used basically this same code on **lottery.net/powerball/numbers/#year** no problem.
Why is it not working this time? I have changed all the info I need to do as in the links and the XPath differences.

```
import scrapy


class MegaMillionsDrawingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'mega_millions_drawings'
        allowed_domains = ['www.lottery.net']
        user_agent = # my user agent
  

def start_request(self):
    start_urls = []
    for i in reversed(range(1996,2023)):
        current_url = 'http://www.lottery.net/mega-millions/numbers/'+ str(i)
        start_urls.append(current_url)
        
    for url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(    
            url=url, 
            callback=self.parse,
            headers={
                'User-Agent': self.user_agent
            }
        )

def parse(self, response):
    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    inspect_response(response, self)

    for drawing in response.xpath("//table[@class='prizes archive ']/tbody/tr"):
        yield {
            'date': drawing.xpath(".//td/a/text()[2]").get(),
            #'url': response.urljoin(drawing.xpath(".//")).get(),
            'first': drawing.xpath(".//td/ul[@class='multi results mega-millions']/li[@class='ball'][position() = 1]/text()").get(),
            'second': drawing.xpath(".//td/ul[@class='multi results mega-millions']/li[@class='ball'][position() = 2]/text()").get(),
            'third': drawing.xpath(".//td/ul[@class='multi results mega-millions']/li[@class='ball'][position() = 3]/text()").get(),
            'fourth': drawing.xpath(".//td/ul[@class='multi results mega-millions']/li[@class='ball'][position() = 4]/text()").get(),
            'fifth': drawing.xpath(".//td/ul[@class='multi results mega-millions']/li[@class='ball'][position() = 5]/text()").get(),
            'mega-ball': drawing.xpath(".//td/ul[@class='multi results mega-millions']/li[@class='mega-ball']/text()").get()
        }
```

Comment: none of you xpath matches from the website you linked, what are you trying to scrape?

Comment: well your indentation is way off.  That might just be a formating problem though

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues that I can see. Some of your xpath expressions are off, the indentation is way off, you are using `http` instead of `https`.

Using the slight modifications to the formatting and your instance methods I made in the example below will fix the issues.

```
import scrapy

class MegaMillionsDrawingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mega-millions-drawings'
    allowed_domains = ['lottery.net']

    def start_requests(self):
        for num in reversed(range(1996, 2023)):  # only need one loop
            url = "https://www.lottery.net/mega-millions/numbers/" + str(num)
            yield scrapy.Request(url)  

    def parse(self, response):
        for drawing in response.xpath("//table[@class='prizes archive ']/tbody/tr"):
            item = {"date" : drawing.xpath(".//td/a/text()[2]").get().strip()}
            for number, text in zip(    # use a loop to gather all the numbers
                ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"],
                drawing.xpath(".//td/ul/li[@class='ball']/text()").getall()
            ):
                item[number] = text.strip()  # remove whitespace
            item["mega-ball"] = drawing.xpath(".//td/ul/li[@class='mega-ball']/text()").getall().strip()
            yield item
```